# publish a project at gitHup pages

Tags: github, github-actions, github-pages

I have created a new respiratory and uploaded all the code (HTML, CSS,js) and images to it and I made the pages main and root and I have checked 5 times on the actions and they all have succeeded and I have waited over more than 35 minutes but it still gives me error 404 files not found this is my project: https://abdelrhmanboy.github.io/Star-Bucks-landing-page/

I tried to wait for 30 minutes and checked 5 times on the Actions and they all has succeeded

in short, I am trying to publish a simple landing page to make it accessible to anyone to see it but it keeps giving me the error 404

NOTE: I am totally new at this.

```js
let image = document.getElementById('main');
let all = document.body;
let container = document.getElementById('container');
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
let can1 = document.getElementById('can1');
let can2 = document.getElementById('can2');
let can3 = document.getElementById('can3');
let face = document.getElementById('F');
let insta = document.getElementById('I');
let twiter = document.getElementById('T');
function pepsi(aaa) {
    image.src = aaa;
}
function color(bbb) {
    all.style.backgroundColor = bbb;
}
function colorc(zzz) {
    container.style.backgroundColor = zzz;
}
can1.onclick = function(){
    // functions
    pepsi(this.src);
    color('#1a1aff')
    colorc(' rgb(9, 59, 158)')

    // btn fuctions
    btn.onmouseenter = function(){
    btn.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(5, 34, 93)';
    btn.style.color = '#fff'
 } ;
    btn.onmouseleave = function(){
    btn.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
    btn.style.color = '#000'
 }
 face.onmouseenter = function(){
    face.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(5, 34, 93)';
 } ;
 face.onmouseleave = function(){
    face.style.removeProperty('background-color');
    
 }
 insta.onmouseenter = function(){
    insta.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(5, 34, 93)';
 } ;
 insta.onmouseleave = function(){
    insta.style.removeProperty('background-color')
    
 }
 twiter.onmouseenter = function(){
    twiter.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(5, 34, 93)';
 } ;
 twiter.onmouseleave = function(){
    twiter.style.removeProperty('background-color')
    
 }
}
can2.onclick = function(){
    // functions
    pepsi(this.src);
    color('#404040')
    colorc('#666768')

    // btn fuctions
    btn.onmouseenter = function(){
    btn.style.backgroundColor = '#393939';
    btn.style.color = '#fff'
 } ;
    btn.onmouseleave = function(){
    btn.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
    btn.style.color = '#000'
 }
 face.onmouseenter = function(){
    face.style.backgroundColor = '#393939';
 } ;
 face.onmouseleave = function(){
    face.style.removeProperty('background-color');
    
 }
 insta.onmouseenter = function(){
    insta.style.backgroundColor = '#393939';
 } ;
 insta.onmouseleave = function(){
    insta.style.removeProperty('background-color')
    
 }
 twiter.onmouseenter = function(){
    twiter.style.backgroundColor = '#393939';
 } ;
 twiter.onmouseleave = function(){
    twiter.style.removeProperty('background-color')
    
 }
}
can3.onclick = function(){
    // functions
    pepsi(this.src);
    color('#111')
    colorc('#222')

    // btn fuctions
    btn.onmouseenter = function(){ 
    btn.style.backgroundColor = '#111';
    btn.style.color = '#fff'
 } ; 
    btn.onmouseleave = function(){
    btn.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
    btn.style.color = '#000'
 }
 face.onmouseenter = function(){
    face.style.backgroundColor = '#111';
 } ;
 face.onmouseleave = function(){
    face.style.removeProperty('background-color');
    
 }
 insta.onmouseenter = function(){
    insta.style.backgroundColor = '#111';
 } ;
 insta.onmouseleave = function(){
    insta.style.removeProperty('background-color')
    
 }
 twiter.onmouseenter = function(){
    twiter.style.backgroundColor = '#111';
 } ;
 twiter.onmouseleave = function(){
    twiter.style.removeProperty('background-color')
    
 }
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}
html{
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
body{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #1a1aff;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
#container{
    background-color: rgb(9, 59, 160);
    width: 85%;
    height: 85%;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 30px 30px 50px #000;
    transition: 0.5s;
    overflow: hidden;
}
header{
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
header a img{
    width: 60px;
}
header ul{
    display: flex;
}
header ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
header ul li a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 600;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
header ul li a:hover{
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.content{
    width: 100%;
    height: 65%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}
.content .image , .content .txt {
    width: 40%;
}
.content .image img{
    width: 180px;
    transform: translateX(130px);
}
.content .txt h2{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.content .txt h1{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: 800;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.content .txt p{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 20px 0;
    
}
.content .txt a{
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    word-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 8px;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
.content .txt a:hover{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgb(5, 34, 93);
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
.icons{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 10px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.icons img{
    width: 40px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    
}
.icons img:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-bottom: 18px;
   
}
.links{
    position: absolute;
    left: 16px;
    bottom: 10px;
}
.links a img{
    width: 16px;
   
    
}
#f{
    width: 10px;
}
.links a{
    transition: 0.3s;
    padding: 9px 9px;
}
.links a:hover{
    background-color: rgb(5, 34, 93);
    border-radius: 50px;
    
}

@media (max-width:950px) and (min-width:720px){
    .links a:hover{
        background:none;
    }
    .links a{
        padding: 6px 6px;
    }
    .links a img{
        width: 13px;
        transform: translateX(-10px);
    }
    #f{
        width: 8px;
    }
    header a img{
        width: 50px;
    }
    header ul li {
        list-style: none;
        margin-right: 17px;
    }
    header ul li a{
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: 500;
        transition: 0.4s;
    }
    .content .image img{
        width: 140px;
    }
    .content .txt h2{
        color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .content .txt h1{
        color: #fff;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .content .txt p{
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 18px;
        margin: 20px 0;
        
        
    }
    .content .txt a{
        font-size: 14px;
    word-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 30px;
    }
    .icons img{
        width: 30px;
    }
}

@media (max-width:720px){
    .links a:hover{
        background: none;
    }
    .links a{
        padding: 4px 4px;
    }
    .links a img{
        width: 10px;
        transform: translateX(-12px);
    }
    #f{
        width: 7px;
    }
    header ul li a{
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 11px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: 400;
        transition: 0.4s;
    }
    header ul li {
        list-style: none;
        margin-right: 15px;
    }
    header a img{
        width: 35px;
    }
    .content .image img{
        width: 90px;
        transform: translateX(40px);
    }
    .content .txt h2{
        color: #fff;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .content .txt h1{
        color: #fff;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .content .txt p{
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 13px;
        margin: 20px 0;
        
    }
    .content .txt a{
        font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 30px;
    }
    .icons img{
        width: 22px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Pepsi-Landig page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="pepsi.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <header>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">What's New</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </header>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="txt">
            <h2>that's what</h2>
            <h1>i like</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. 
               Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Saepe aut nesciunt eveniet natus, ullam eaque.</p>
               <a id="btn" href="#">Veiw all Products</a>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
            <img id="main" src="images/pepsi001.png">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="icons">
            <img id="can1" src="images/pepsi001.png">
            <img id="can2" src="images/pepsi002.png">
            <img id="can3" src="images/pepsi003.png">
        </div>
        <div class="links">
           <a id="F" href="#"><img id="f" src="images/facebook.png"></a> 
           <a id="I" href="#"><img  src="images/twitter.png"></a>  
           <a id="T" href="#"><img  src="images/instagram.png"></a>  
        </div>
        
    </div>
    <script src="pepsi.js"></script>
</body>
</html>



<!-- REMEMBER TO WRITE CLEAN CODE -->

<!-- <div class="icons">
    <img onclick="pepsi(this.src) ; color('#1a1aff') ; colorc(' rgb(9, 59, 158)') ;
     let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
      btn.onmouseenter = function(){ btn.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(5, 34, 93)';
     btn.style.color = '#fff'} ;
     btn.onmouseleave = function(){
        btn.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
        btn.style.color = '#000'}"
      src="F:\work4\Developer\Projects\1Items\PEPSI\pepsi001.png">
    <img onclick="pepsi(this.src) ; color('#404040') ; colorc('#666768') ;
    let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
     btn.onmouseenter = function(){ btn.style.backgroundColor = '#393939';
    btn.style.color = '#fff'} ;
    btn.onmouseleave = function(){
        btn.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
        btn.style.color = '#000'}"
     src="F:\work4\Developer\Projects\1Items\PEPSI\pepsi002.png">
    <img onclick="pepsi(this.src) ; color('#111') ; colorc('#222') ;
    let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
     btn.onmouseenter = function(){ btn.style.backgroundColor = '#111';
    btn.style.color = '#fff'} ; 
    btn.onmouseleave = function(){
        btn.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
        btn.style.color = '#000'}" 
    src="F:\work4\Developer\Projects\1Items\PEPSI\pepsi003.png">
</div> -->
```

Comment: To avoid being closed due to lack of actionable information, please supply: a valid link - yours is broken for me; the URL you are seeing the 404 on; If you are looking to actually deploy a web site, know that this is different from a code repository. It's hard to tell what you are trying to do and with what whitout more details.

Comment: There is a link on the 404 page to a page explaining the steps required to get this working.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant I am trying to publish a project to make it public and accessible to anyone and that project is a simple landing page

Comment: @Dreamer2005 I can't see your repo or the code and without that it's hard for us to help you. I got 404's for all the URLs i try.  If you heave a public github repo you should be able to tell us what your github repo url is and provide us with its URL Help us help you :)

Comment: I am trying to help and prevent the question from being closed.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant yeah I know man thanks for your interest but I am new at git hup so I don't know what repo is, and do you want the code of the landing page? ok i will upload it.

Comment: @Dreamer2005 no worries, learning is life long.  My advice for the next step is to remove nearly all the code and leave the simplest possible code to test. So like just one function and whatever css is needed to support that. The issue is in configuration not code so once people see a small amount of code not working they can help focus on configuration. I would also recheck their documentation and search further for blogs etc. It is likely a small thing or step or understanding that will fix your issue.